# PowerShell DSC Group Resource - "Could not find a principal with the provided name"

Tags: windows, active-directory, powershell, groups, dsc

I am trying to use PowerShell DSC to add a domain group to the local administrators group. Here is the code:

```
Configuration TestSetup {
    Node localhost {
        Group Administrators {
            GroupName = "Administrators"
            MembersToInclude = "MYDOMAIN\TheAdministratorsGroup"
        }
    }
}
```

This is resulting in the following error when I run it:

```
PowerShell provider MSFT_GroupResource  failed to execute Test-TargetResource functionality with error message: Could not find a principal with the provided name [mydomain\theadministratorsgroup]
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ProviderOperationExecutionFailure
    + PSComputerName        : localhost
```

The principal does exist and I can add it manually through the GUI and using `net localgroup`.

I know that DSC configurations get executed under the `SYSTEM` account so I thought it might be a permissions issue with the `SYSTEM` account wanting to query Active Directory. However I've run a cmd as the `SYSTEM` account using PsExec and I was able to add a domain group to the local administrators group without any trouble.

Answer (score 4):

You have to specify the credentials:

Example:

Way to get the credentials:

```
$securedstring = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $Password -AsPlainText -Force
[PSCredential]$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($UserName, $securedstring)
```

And this is the code u need to configure the DSC resource

```
$ConfigurationData = @{
    AllNodes = @(
        @{
            NodeName="*"
            PSDscAllowPlainTextPassword=$true
         }
        @{
            NodeName="SRV2-WS2012R2"
         }
        @{
            NodeName="SRV3-WS2012R2"
         }
   )
}


Node $AllNodes.NodeName
{
    LocalConfigurationManager
    {
        RebootNodeIfNeeded = $false
    }

    Group $group.Name
    {
        GroupName = $group.Name
        Ensure = $group.Ensure
        Members = $group.Members
        Credential = $cred
    }
}
```

Then simply execute

```
ProcessDscResources -ConfigurationData $ConfigurationData -OutputPath $folderPathTmp

Start-DscConfiguration -Wait -Force -Path $folderPathTmp
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jupaoi, this was helpful and fairly undocumented in the official docs.

Comment: Is there a way to tell it, it should just use "the current credentials"